# Oracle Java javac runtime error

Tags: 11.04, java

I have been trying to install Oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu 11.04. I was following the [instructions given here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Once I followed all the steps ( to the letter ), I tried running

```
java -version
```

which gave the expected output. But running

```
javac -version
```

did not give the expected output. Instead I get the following error:

```
Error : Could not find libjava.so
Error : Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment
```

The environment variable PATH contains both /usr/local/java/jre/bin and /usr/local/java/jdk/bin, LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to /usr/local/lib which contains libjava.so which is currently owned by the user who I am running javac as. In addition, JAVA_HOME points to the jdk folder. Inspite of all this, javac is unable to find the libjava.so file. There are multiple solutions online but none seem to work for me. Even a direct run

```
/usr/locale/java/jdk/bin/javac -version
```

results in the same error.

Any help is hugely appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be exact solution that you want, but could try this:
If you install JDK by this method:

---

### Linux Jdk installation

## Adds PPA for JDK

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

## Updates PPA

```
sudo apt-get update
```

## Installs JDK

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```